# Apache Spark 2.0 (PySpark) - DataFrame Error Multiple sources found for csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a dataframe using the following code in Spark 2.0. While executing the code in Jupyter/Console, I am facing the below error. Can someone help me how to get rid of this error?

**Error:**

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.csv.
>   : java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple sources found for csv (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat, com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource15), please specify the fully qualified class name.
>       at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)

**Code:**

```
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      session = SparkSession.builder.master('local')
                     .appName("RealEstateSurvey").getOrCreate()
      df = session \
           .read \
           .option("inferSchema", value = True) \
           .option('header','true') \
           .csv("/home/senthiljdpm/RealEstate.csv")

     print("=== Print out schema ===")
     session.stop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because you must have both libraries (`org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat` and `com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource`) in your classpath. And spark got confused which one to choose.

All you need is tell spark to use `com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource` by defining `format` option as

```
  df = session \
       .read \
       .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
       .option("inferSchema", value = True) \
       .option('header','true') \
       .csv("/home/senthiljdpm/RealEstate.csv")
```

Another alternative is to use `load` as

```
  df = session \
       .read \
       .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
       .option("inferSchema", value = True) \
       .option('header','true') \
       .load("/home/senthiljdpm/RealEstate.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh.. but faced same error even after adding the line you suggested

Comment: It works. Thanks Ramesh.. But what's the difference?

Comment: I got similar error between 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.csv.CSVDataSourceV2' and 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat'. Adding one of them to .format made no difference. .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv")

Answer (score 4):

If anyone faced a similar issue in Spark Java, it could be because you have multiple versions of the spark-sql jar in your classpath. Just FYI.

Comment: How would I know? I have "multiple sources found for json"

Comment: I am using spark 3 and migrated old code to spark 3. I am getting error as : pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for json (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.json.JsonDataSourceV2, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat), please specify the fully qualified class name.;

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue, and got fixed when changed the Hudi version used in pom.xml from 9.0 to 11.1