# Spark Multiple sources found for text

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Java jar, coming from a Java program, if I run the Java program locally within IntelliJ IDEA, it is working well.

When I have compiled the Java program into a jar file.
If I run the program as `java -cp jarFileName.jar com.pathToclass.ClassName  inputArguments`, it works well.

However, when I run as
`spark-submit --master local[4] --class  com.pathToclass.ClassName jarFileName.jar inputArguments`, I have the following error when the Java code runs into the `read.textFile` function.

The code is as follows:

```
DataFrameReader read = spark.read()；
JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD = read.textFile(inputPath).javaRDD();
```

Within the inputPath, are some csv files. The error message when running with `spark-submit` is as follows:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for text (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.text.TextDataSourceV2, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat), please specify the fully qualified class name.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:707)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:880)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:852)
    at com.three2three.bigfoot.vola.NormalizeSnapshotSigmaAxisImpliedVola.main(NormalizeSnapshotSigmaAxisImpliedVola.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried to debug locally within IntelliJ IDEA,  when running in IDEA, the data source is found to be `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat`.

It seems that when running as `spark-submit`, `this.source()` is `text`, and the scala code found two datasources:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.text.TextDataSourceV2
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat
```

Why it is like this? Why the code failed only when running in `spark-submit` mode, and succeeded in other running ways? How to solve the error for running in `spark-submit` mode?

I tested running with `spark-submit`. It worked one Linux server, but failed on my windows PC and another linux server (with different version of hadoop and spark).

Updating,in some post, it is claimed that if specifying the format, such `mutiple source found for ...` error can be avoided.
e.g. In this post: https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/issues/147, they hard-coded

```
    df = (
    spark
    .readStream
    .schema(stream_schema)
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat")
    .load("path_to_stream_directory")
)
```

The "multi soruce found for json" error is gone. Similary, I saw post about format for csv. But I tried with hard-coded format in my case, it does not work either.

[image]

Comment: While running with `spark-submit`, it works well when running on the Linux server. However, it failed when running on the Windows pc, with the error message `Spark Multiple sources found for text`

Comment: I installed the newest version of spark, hadoop, and java. Now the same error happens again. My version is Debian 10, hadoop-3.2.2, java: openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
, spark: spark.3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2

Comment: Similar error for "multiple source found for parquet" : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24427, and "multiple source found for csv": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884599/apache-spark-2-0-pyspark-dataframe-error-multiple-sources-found-for-csv

Comment: the error seems from source code: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.
The "Multiple sources found for ..." indicate that multiple packages are found for reading text/csv files when submitting the spark job in `spark-submit`.

So, it is likely that the multiple versions of the library used for reading text/csv files have been found.

I assume the cause are as follows:
I compiled my java code with gradle on my Windows pc with particular hadoop/spark version. I have run the `spark-submit --someCofigaration myjar.jar --some parameters` locally on my windows PC and on different linux server. The version specified in the gradle.build file may not be the same as on my Windows pc. Lucikly it is the same with the version on one of the linux server, and different with the version on another linux server. That is why the `spark-submit` job only succeed on one of the linux server and failed on the other one and the Windows pc.

After realizing it could potentially the problem of version conflicts, I re-installed the most recent versions on my pc/linux and the `spark-submit` works well, without the error of "mutilple source found for ...".

The versions I am currently using are as follows:

Hadoop:  hadoop-3.2.2

Spark: spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2

java: openjdk version “1.8.0_282“ (Java 8)

Flume: apache-flume-1.9.0-bin

Kafka: kafka_2.13-2.7.0

Scala: scala-2.12.13.deb

sbt: sbt-1.5.0.tgz

I am not sure whether my answer is indeed the correct one as I am relatively new to hadoop/spark/java.  If someone knows the reason in details, please post your answer.